# phpstorm watcher аргументы

Tags: node.js, phpstorm, cmd, jetbrains

Нужно слить все `.coffee` файлы в папке в один файл. Согласно документации предлагается такой вариант

```
coffee --compile project.js --join *.coffee
```

Выдает ошибку, мол, файл "*.coffee" не найден, то есть не интерпретирует как надо. Так же предупреждение, что метод `--join` устарел и следует использовать такую конструкцию

```
cat *.coffee | coffee --compile --stdio > project.js
```

Проблема в том, что смотритель принимает только аргументы для самой программы. Нужно именно через встроенный в ide смотритель. Как правильно сделать, что бы выполняло свою задачу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--joi`n по-прежнему работает, только передавать этой опции нужно имя js файла, например: `--map --join $ProjectFileDir$/project.js --compile $ProjectFileDir$/src` скомпилирует все .coffee файлы в директории src в файл project.js, лежащий в корне проекта. Если Вы хотите использовать cat, я бы посоветовала написать для этой команды собственный shell script и его уже запускать как file watcher (прописать в качестве Program).

А вообще есть другие удобные решения этой проблемы, скажем, https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee. PHPStorm включает интеграцию с Grunt